# Why is my mix in my shader not properly mixing in Threejs?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I have been messing with this for awhile and I cannot get the shader to mix properly. Currently it is displaying the two colors that are supposed to be mixed as two separate colors on each hemisphere. I am new to threejs and often certain details I am missing. I would appreciate any help regarding this code.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);

const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF);
scene.add(spotLight);
spotLight.position.set(0, 0, 100);

spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.angle = 0.2;
spotLight.intensity = 0.2;

camera.position.set(0.27, 0, 500);

//Black center
var geom = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(100, 32, 32);
var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x000000
});


const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: `

  varying vec3 vPosition;



  void main() {
  
      vPosition = position;
  
      vec4 localPosition = vec4(position, 1.0);
  
      vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * localPosition;
  
      vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * worldPosition;
  
      vec4 clipPosition = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;
  
      gl_Position = clipPosition;
  }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `

  varying vec3 vPosition;

  void main() {
  
      float depth = vPosition.x;
  
      vec3 color1 = vec3(1., 1.0, 1.0);
      vec3 color2 = vec3(0., .0, 1.0);
  
      vec3 mixedColor = mix(color1, color2, depth);
      gl_FragColor = vec4(mixedColor, 1.0);
  }
  `
});

var core = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
scene.add(core);

var geom = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1, 15, 15);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff
});

var atoms = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(atoms);
for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
  var nucleus = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
  var size = Math.random() * 6 + 1.5;
  nucleus.speedX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.08;
  nucleus.speedY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.08;
  nucleus.speedZ = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.08;
  nucleus.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(size, size, size));
  nucleus.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 100 + Math.random() * 10, 0));
  nucleus.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(Math.random() * (Math.PI * 2)));
  nucleus.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.random() * (Math.PI * 2)));
  nucleus.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.random() * (Math.PI * 2)));
  atoms.add(nucleus);
}

const _matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
function updateNucleus(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < atoms.children.length; i++) {
    var part = atoms.children[i];
    part.applyMatrix4(_matrix.makeRotationX(part.speedX));
    part.applyMatrix4(_matrix.makeRotationY(part.speedY));
    part.applyMatrix4(_matrix.makeRotationZ(part.speedZ));
  }
}
//Create scene
var necks = [];
var cubesObject = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(cubesObject);



function animate(a) {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    updateNucleus(a);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
};
animate();

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / this.window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
})
```

Comment: `vec3 mixedColor = mix(color1, color2, depth);`, I would start with `smoothstep` for the third parameter, thus it will be something like this: `vec3 mixedColor = mix(color1, color2, smoothstep(-1., 1., depth));`

Comment: The smoothstep worked perfectly. Its just the tutorial I was following didn't use it and it worked for them. Weird, this is the tutorial if you are curious and they posted to github in the description. https://youtu.be/Sukvxf7FfYM